# Emulate hover on iPad chart

Tags: highcharts

my customer wants to drag his finger over the chart and get a tooltip without a tap. The app is built on EnyoJS and it dispatches 'move' event to dom elements when finger is moving above it as well as 'enter'/'leave' when finger enters and leaves element. I have two questions:

1. Is there configuration option which enables this feature in Highcharts 3?
2. If no, how can I attach custom event listeners to the point ( or chart but get point in the handler )?

Thanks,
Max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the changelog release 3.0.1 ( http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog ), you should be able to do this with the tooltip.followTouchMove property:

EDIT:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.followTouchMove